# Angular2 ng-bootstrap modal components

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I have a [modal component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal) created with [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) like follow (just a body):

```
<template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

And it's **angular 2 component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-hello-home-modal',
    templateUrl: './hellohome.modal.html'
})

export class HelloHomeModalComponent {
    closeResult: string;

    constructor(private modal: NgbModal) {}

    open(content) {
        this.modal.open(content).result.then((result) => {
            this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
        }, (reason) => {
            console.log(reason);
        });
    }
}
```

I really want to be able to call this modal from an other component in my web site. **I just want call from my homeComponent the open method.**

**See my homeComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Hello Home');

        /** want call modal popin here from the init component method in order to test the modal. **/

    }
}
```

Someone can explain me how to do that ? I came from angular 1.x and it was so much simpler ...

Comment: there are 2 good answers already but I think that we are struggling to give you _exact_ answer since the question is not super-clear... If you could put your code in a plunker (you can use one of mains as a starting point) than you would get exact answer in no time.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is how I do it with Angular 5 and ng-bootstrap. Create your modal component as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbActiveModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'sm-create-asset-modal',
  templateUrl: './create-asset-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-asset-modal.component.css']
})
export class CreateAssetModalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public activeModal: NgbActiveModal) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

and the template will be something like:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4 class="modal-title">Create New </h4>
  <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="activeModal.dismiss('Cross click')">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="activeModal.close('Close click')">Create</button>
</div>
```

In the component where you want to open the modal from add a variable of type NgbModal and call open as follows:

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private modal: NgbModal) {}

  onClick() {
    this.modal.open(CreateAssetModalComponent);
  }

}
```

In the NgModule where the CreateAssetModalComponent is declared add the component in the entryComponents array as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [CreateAssetModalComponent],
  entryComponents: [CreateAssetModalComponent]
})
```

Assuming you have other Modules like NgbModule imported this should work.

Comment: Thanks! Works for me, but... why the documetation dont explain why "entryComponents: [CreateAssetModalComponent]" ??????

Comment: The best answer for this. Thank you!

Comment: great, thanks! how can i pass to the modal component some parameters? in the doc nothing is tell about it.

Comment: Best Solution! Thank God this post was at top on google search, saved me hours!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I *fully* understand what you are trying to do but in the essence it is *very* simple - to open a modal window with a specific *content* you just call the `open` method on the `NgbModal` service. The *simplest* possible implementation would be a one-liner (`this.modalService.open('Hi tehre!');`):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-home',
  templateUrl: 'src/modal-basic.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  ngOnInit(content) {
    this.modalService.open('Hi tehre!');
  }
}
```

See it live in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5qq04Q4HFLOe9tsyeMMI?p=preview

It is *exactly* the same as in angular-ui/bootstrap for AngularJS 1.x! Principles are exactly the same, nothing have changed.

What *might* be giving you headaches is how to specify *content* of the modal. In the above example I'm using a string but in vast majority of cases you want to use HTML with bindings, directives etc. But Angular is different as you just can't pass HTML string if you don't want to ship compiler to production (and you really don't want to do this...).

So your next best option is to use *another* component as content, here is a minimal example: http://plnkr.co/edit/EJyZ6nF5WVAS9bvQycQe?p=preview

**Note**: due to a bug in the Angular itself you need to currently wrap the `open()` method call with the `setTimeout`. Bug reference: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15634

Comment: When i call this open method from homeComponent I had this error
**core.es5.js?0445:1085 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for HelloHomeModalComponent!**

Comment: @user7339839 it is _really_ not clear what you are trying to do _exactly_ ... Please try to reproduce your _exact_ problem in a plunker (you can use one from this answer as a starting point) - otherwise it is super hard to help....

Comment: I am just trying open a modal from my home component, not just by clicking in a html button
And my modal that I want to open is also a component. Very simple

Comment: @user7339839  but this is _exactly_ what I'm showing in my answer in this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/EJyZ6nF5WVAS9bvQycQe?p=preview - did you ever look at it?

Comment: Ok, so u tell to angular to copy the modal component html content to the other component with export class NgbdModalContent ?

Comment: Yes, as explained in the answer the content of a modal can be one of: string (not very useful as can't contain HTML), another component (as shown in the plnkr.co/edit/EJyZ6nF5WVAS9bvQycQe?p=preview). There is a third option of passing a template reference (shown on our demo page)

Comment: Ok ok, i validate your answer but it's not really what I expected. I thought we can just call method from another component and not pass html or string from a method to one other

Comment: @user7339839 if you feel like there is a use-case that is not covered or you have a proposal for a better API feel free to open an issue on https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues

Answer (score 1):

Add the `HelloHomeModalComponent` to your constructor parameters and call the `open` function from HomeComponent like so:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HelloHomeModalComponent } from "hello-home-modal.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private modal: HelloHomeModalComponent) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.modal.open();
    }
}
```

You don't need to pass a `content` parameter to your component's `open()` if you use @ViewRef() to get the appropriate template reference from the modal component.

Comment: I should have to say I had already tried that, I have an error from providers.

**core.es5.js?0445:1085 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for HelloHomeModalComponent!**

Comment: @user7339839 You should add your HelloHomeModalComponent to the same module that contains HomeComponent

Comment: I have just one module bootstraped by angular

Comment: @user7339839 could you post the contents of your bootstrapped module?

Comment: "Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target." It needs a parameter.